# DefaultEncapsulation in angular-cli --prod

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've created a basic application using angular-cli command `ng new MyProject` and to disable view encapsulation globally I changed main.ts file by adding defaultEncapsulation: `bootstrapModule(AppModule,{ defaultEncapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None })`.

It works perfectly if I start the application using `ng serve`, but if I use `ng serve --prod`, my configuration is ignored and the application is served with `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` (I can see _ngcontent attributes in dev tools). Any idea what am I missing and how to set `ViewEncapsulation.None` in prod build? I use angular 4.1.3 and angular-cli 1.0.0.

**Update:**
If I build the application using `ng serve --prod --aot=false` my configuration is also respected, so it has something to do with aot.

Comment: Have the same problem in 4.4.6 and 1.4.8 — have to run --aot=false on production build.

Comment: Relevant issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12251